# Drag and drop sortable ng:repeats in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it at all easy to use **`jQuery.sortable`** on **`ng-repeat`** elements in AngularJS?

---

It would be awesome if re-ordering the items automatically propagated that ordering back into the source array.  I'm afraid the two systems would fight though.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it possible that you update the js fiddle codes for angular js current version i.e. angular js 1.0.1. I tried to run the examples on jsfiddle by changing the version of angular js to 1.0.1 as per my requirements but then the code breaks and doesnot work. Kindly help.' Thanks !

Comment: Im on board with that. Also looking for a working example for 1.0.1 :-)

Comment: Found this, which works in 1.0.1 - http://jsfiddle.net/007design/KHqbM/

Comment: I've created a tutorial on how to do this in combination with JQuery UI. Very easy to do with a single directive. Explanation and examples can be found here: http://www.smartjava.org/content/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Angular UI has a sortable directive,[Click Here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/)

Code located at [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable), usage:

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="items" ui-sortable-update="sorted">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" id="{{$index}}">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.sorted = (event, ui) => { console.log(ui.item[0].getAttribute('id')) }
```

Comment: Notice that you should add `ng-model` with `ui:sortable`: `<ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">`

Comment: Any error in the console? Works in my chrome/windows 7, you can try to update the libs (jquery/jqueryUI/angular/angularUI) and see if it's solving your problem...

Comment: i'm getting an error too, it can't find the reference UI module. "Uncaught Error: No module: ui "

Comment: I changed the script URL to a CDN, it's fixed (chrome enabled MIME type checking, breaking js served from raw.github)

Comment: Damn. I was hoping there would be an option that doesn't involve jQueryUI. I'm building a site for mobile devices, and I don't want to have to download an entire library just for that one function.

Comment: If you don't need old IE support there is a few lightweight alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658300/jquery-sortable-without-jquery-ui

Comment: The jsfiddle example does not seem to work reliably. There are no errors but the order intermittently becomes out of sync.  Tried in firefox and chrome

Comment: Try the latest versions of angular and angular-ui. They are both moving fast, answers get outdated.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this without jQuery?

Comment: you can create your own directive from another javascript component, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333077/lightweight-alternative-to-jquery-uis-sortable

Comment: @Kugel did you even tried the last version of angular-ui sortable? At the rate angular evolve the demos get outdated very quickly: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Comment: Can this be applied to a table or does it have to be a list?

Comment: You can use it on < tr >

Comment: @Guillaume86 How to use it for touch devices?

Answer (score 12):

I tried to do the same and came up with the following solution:

```
angular.directive("my:sortable", function(expression, compiledElement){
    return function(linkElement){
        var scope = this;
        linkElement.sortable(
        {
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            opacity: 0.8,
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var model = scope.$tryEval(expression);
                var newModel = [];
                var items = [];
                linkElement.children().each(function() {
                    var item = $(this);
                    // get old item index
                    var oldIndex = item.attr("ng:repeat-index");
                    if(oldIndex) {
                        // new model in new order
                        newModel.push(model[oldIndex]);
                        // items in original order
                        items[oldIndex] = item;
                        // and remove
                        item.detach();
                    }
                });
                // restore original dom order, so angular does not get confused
                linkElement.append.apply(linkElement,items);

                // clear old list
                model.length = 0;
                // add elements in new order
                model.push.apply(model, newModel);

                // presto
                scope.$eval();

                // Notify event handler
                var onSortExpression = linkElement.attr("my:onsort");
                if(onSortExpression) {
                    scope.$tryEval(onSortExpression, linkElement);
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Used like this:

```
<ol id="todoList" my:sortable="todos" my:onsort="onSort()">
```

It seems to work fairly well. The trick is to undo the DOM manipulation made by sortable before updating the model, otherwise angular gets desynchronized from the DOM.

Notification of the changes works via the my:onsort expression which can call the controller methods.

I created a JsFiddle based on the angular todo tutorial to shows how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/M8YnR/180/

Answer (score 10):

This is how I am doing it with angular v0.10.6. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTppE/)

```
angular.directive("my:sortable", function(expression, compiledElement){
    // add my:sortable-index to children so we know the index in the model
    compiledElement.children().attr("my:sortable-index","{{$index}}");

    return function(linkElement){
        var scope = this;            

        linkElement.sortable({
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            opacity: 0.8,
            axis: "y",
            update: function(event, ui) {
                // get model
                var model = scope.$apply(expression);
                // remember its length
                var modelLength = model.length;
                // rember html nodes
                var items = [];

                // loop through items in new order
                linkElement.children().each(function(index) {
                    var item = $(this);

                    // get old item index
                    var oldIndex = parseInt(item.attr("my:sortable-index"), 10);

                    // add item to the end of model
                    model.push(model[oldIndex]);

                    if(item.attr("my:sortable-index")) {
                        // items in original order to restore dom
                        items[oldIndex] = item;
                        // and remove item from dom
                        item.detach();
                    }
                });

                model.splice(0, modelLength);

                // restore original dom order, so angular does not get confused
                linkElement.append.apply(linkElement,items);

                // notify angular of the change
                scope.$digest();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I ended up just using SlickGrid for this, but I'll take your word that this works.

Comment: One thing to note with this solution is that it will most likely not work as is with v1.x. It shouldn't be to hard to tweak this, but I haven't gotten around to updating all of my code yet.

Comment: @respectTheCode Have you re-factored the code to work with the latest AngularJS version (v1.0.1)? I can't for the life of me find a reliable working version for 1.0.1....

Comment: @Greg we are using Angular-UI's UI-Sortable now and it works great. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Answer (score 6):

Here's my implementation of sortable Angular.js directive without jquery.ui :

- https://github.com/schartier/angular-sortable

Answer (score 0):

you can go for ng-sortable directive which is lightweight and it does not uses jquery. here is link [ng-sortable drag and drop elements](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

[Demo for ng-sortable](http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/kanban)