# How do I move divs around?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of elements in HTML, like this:

```
<div>Information Div</div>
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
```

What I need to do is move the `Information Div` around the DOM, so that it appears after whichever div the user clicks on.  So, if the user clicks on `Div 1`, the new DOM would look like:

```
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Information Div</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
```

This is pretty easy with jQuery, but I gather direct DOM manipulation is frowned upon in Angular.  Is there a way of doing this easily with AngularJS?

To add an additional twist, the `Information Div` should always appear *above* the final div, so if the user clicked `Div 2` *or `Div 3`, the DOM would look like:

```
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Information Div</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
```

Comment: you can wrap the jquery logic in directive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354992/drag-and-drop-sortable-ngrepeats-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

You could have the content be in a ng-repeat.  You could then add an orderBy filter to the repeat that sorts in the order you specify.  You could easily add a click event to change the sort order based on the rules you defined above.

orderBy: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy