# How to Create simple drag and Drop in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to know how to do drag and drop by using AngularJs.

This is what I have so far:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><span>SelectAll</span></span>
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">

    <div ng-hide="enableEditor">
        <a href="#">Drag</a>
        <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master" ng-model="todo.done">

        <span ng-if="checked" ng-show="removed" ng-bind="todo.task_name" class="removed"></span>
        <span ng-bind="todo.task_name"></span>
        <span ng-bind="todo.state"></span>
        <a href="#" ng-click="editTask(todo.task_id,todo.task_name,editMode=!editMode)">Edit</a> 

       </div>
       </div>

    <div ng-show="enableEditor">
     <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="todo.task_name"  ng-change="update(todo.task_id,todo.task_name)">
     <a href="#" ng-click="saveTask(todo.task_id,todo.task_name,editMode=!editMode)">Save</a>
     <a href="#" ng-click="cancelTask(todo.task_id,todo.task_name,editMode=!editMode)">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/llTH9nRic3O2S7XMIi6y?p=preview..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and drop sortable ng:repeats in Angular.JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354992/drag-and-drop-sortable-ngrepeats-in-angular-js)

Comment: https://github.com/siddmegadeth/angularjs-drag-and-drop

Comment: Check Angular Material 7 Drag and Drop Example here https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-drag-and-drop-across-multi-lists-in-angular-material-7/

Answer (score 74):

I just posted this to my brand spanking new blog: 
http://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/angularjs-drag-and-drop/

Code here:
https://github.com/logicbomb/lvlDragDrop

Demo here: http://logicbomb.github.io/ng-directives/drag-drop.html

Here are the directives these rely on a UUID service which I've included below:

```
var module = angular.module("lvl.directives.dragdrop", ['lvl.services']);

module.directive('lvlDraggable', ['$rootScope', 'uuid', function($rootScope, uuid) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
                console.log("linking draggable element");

                angular.element(el).attr("draggable", "true");
                var id = attrs.id;
                if (!attrs.id) {
                    id = uuid.new()
                    angular.element(el).attr("id", id);
                }

                el.bind("dragstart", function(e) {
                    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', id);

                    $rootScope.$emit("LVL-DRAG-START");
                });

                el.bind("dragend", function(e) {
                    $rootScope.$emit("LVL-DRAG-END");
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

module.directive('lvlDropTarget', ['$rootScope', 'uuid', function($rootScope, uuid) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                onDrop: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
                var id = attrs.id;
                if (!attrs.id) {
                    id = uuid.new()
                    angular.element(el).attr("id", id);
                }

                el.bind("dragover", function(e) {
                  if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                  }

                  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
                  return false;
                });

                el.bind("dragenter", function(e) {
                  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
                  angular.element(e.target).addClass('lvl-over');
                });

                el.bind("dragleave", function(e) {
                  angular.element(e.target).removeClass('lvl-over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
                });

                el.bind("drop", function(e) {
                  if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                  }

                  if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                  }
                    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                    var dest = document.getElementById(id);
                    var src = document.getElementById(data);

                    scope.onDrop({dragEl: src, dropEl: dest});
                });

                $rootScope.$on("LVL-DRAG-START", function() {
                    var el = document.getElementById(id);
                    angular.element(el).addClass("lvl-target");
                });

                $rootScope.$on("LVL-DRAG-END", function() {
                    var el = document.getElementById(id);
                    angular.element(el).removeClass("lvl-target");
                    angular.element(el).removeClass("lvl-over");
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

UUID service

```
angular
.module('lvl.services',[])
.factory('uuid', function() {
    var svc = {
        new: function() {
            function _p8(s) {
                var p = (Math.random().toString(16)+"000000000").substr(2,8);
                return s ? "-" + p.substr(0,4) + "-" + p.substr(4,4) : p ;
            }
            return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
        },

        empty: function() {
          return '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
    };

    return svc;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this code in Angular 1.2.6. "Multiple directives [lvlDropTarget, tooltip] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div ...". Looks like a collision with bootstrap tooltips.

Comment: I think `stopPropogation` here should be `stopPropagation`. Can't do the edit myself as it's less than 6 characters :/

Comment: @AndrewMagee It has been updated in github - https://github.com/logicbomb/lvlDragDrop

Comment: Why do your attribute names start with `x-` when the directive names don't?

Comment: Prefixing a nonstandard attribute with `x-` allows the HTML to pass valuation.   It's not necessary,  and I probably shouldn't have added them.

Comment: If including jQuery and your getting an **"Cannot call method 'setData' of undefined"** error. Use `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer` instead of `e.dataTransfer`

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but the grid looks promising

Comment: `$rootScope.$on` Gross

Answer (score 26):

Angular doesn't provide snazzy UI elements like drag and drop. That's not really Angular's purpose. However, there are a few well known directives that provide drag and drop. Here are two that I've used.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

Comment: which would you advise?

Answer (score 12):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I have my own directive that looks like it'll fit your case (You can adapt it yourself). It's a modification of the ng-repeat directive that's specifically built for list re-ordering via DnD. I built it as I don't like JQuery UI (preference for less libraries than anything else) also I wanted mine to work on touch screens too ;).

Code is here: http://codepen.io/SimeonC/pen/AJIyC

Blog post is here: http://sdevgame.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/angularjs-drag-n-drop-re-order-in-ngrepeat/

Answer (score 5):

Modified from the **angular-drag-and-drop-lists** [examples page](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple)

#### Markup

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="(listName, list) in models.lists" class="col-md-6">
        <ul dnd-list="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in list" 
                dnd-draggable="item" 
                dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)" 
                dnd-effect-allowed="move" 
                dnd-selected="models.selected = item" 
                ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}" 
                draggable="true">{{item.label}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Angular

```
var app = angular.module('angular-starter', [
    'ui.router',
    'dndLists'
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.models = {
        selected: null,
        lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
    };

    // Generate initial model
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        $scope.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
        $scope.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});
    }

    // Model to JSON for demo purpose
    $scope.$watch('models', function(model) {
        $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
    }, true);
});
```

Library can be installed via bower or npm: **angular-drag-and-drop-lists**

Comment: This is awesome. It has all the features in it

Comment: thank you for this, it's not clear on the documentation :) this is much more easy :)

Comment: How to include it in my project once after installing it through npm

Comment: @MMR You can do it in the following way: `angular.module("demo", ["dndLists"]);` Replace "demo" with your app name. Add `angular-drag-and-drop-lists.min.js` to the script tag in your HTML file. That should do it.

Answer (score 4):

[adapt-strap](http://adaptv.github.io/adapt-strap/) has very light weight module for this.
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashjs/n2gxobf7/). 
Here are some attributes that are supported. There are more.

```
ad-drag="true"
ad-drag-data="car"
ad-drag-begin="onDragStart($data, $dragElement, $event);"
ad-drag-end="onDataEnd($data, $dragElement, $event);"
```

Answer (score 0):

**small scripts for drag and drop by angular**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('drag', []).
  directive('draggable', function($document) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
      element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       border: '1px solid red',
       backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
       cursor: 'pointer',
       display: 'block',
       width: '65px'
      });
      element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        // Prevent default dragging of selected content
        event.preventDefault();
        startX = event.screenX - x;
        startY = event.screenY - y;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove(event) {
        y = event.screenY - startY;
        x = event.screenX - startX;
        element.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left:  x + 'px'
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

[source link](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Using HTML 5 Drag and Drop**
You can easily archive this using HTML 5 drag and drop feature along with angular directives.

1. Enable drag by setting draggable = true.
2. Add directives for parent container and child items.
3. Override drag and drop functions - 'ondragstart' for parent and 'ondrop' for child.

Find the example below in which `list` is array of items.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="item_content" ng-repeat="item in list" draggrble-container>
        <div class="item" draggable-item draggable="true">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    module.directive("draggableItem",function(){
     return {
      link:function(scope,elem,attr){
        elem[0].ondragstart = function(event){
            scope.$parent.selectedItem = scope.item;
        };
      }
     };
    });


    module.directive("draggrbleContainer",function(){
     return {
        link:function(scope,elem,attr){
            elem[0].ondrop = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                let selectedIndex = scope.list.indexOf(scope.$parent.selectedItem);
                let newPosition = scope.list.indexOf(scope.item);
                scope.$parent.list.splice(selectedIndex,1);
                scope.$parent.list.splice(newPosition,0,scope.$parent.selectedItem);
                scope.$apply();
            };
            elem[0].ondragover = function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

            };
        }
     };
    });
```

Find the complete code here https://github.com/raghavendrarai/SimpleDragAndDrop

Comment: 'ondrop' function doesn't trigger for me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Example simple
<div on-drag="dataToTransfer" draggable="true"></div>
<div on-drop="onDropFunction"></div>

Example 2: use a getter function and pass index and name
<div on-drag="getData" index="2" name="'start'" draggable="true"></div>
<div on-drop="onDropFunction" drop-data="dropData"></div>
```

```js
app.directive('onDrag', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
         onDrag: '=',
         index: '=?',
         name: '=?'
      },
      link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
         elem[0].ondragstart = function (event) {
            event.dataTransfer.clearData('text');
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            var data = {};
            if ($scope.onDrag) {
               if (typeof $scope.onDrag === 'function') {
                  data.data = $scope.onDrag();
               } else {
                  data.data = $scope.onDrag;
               }
            }
            if ($scope.index) data.index = $scope.index;
            if ($scope.name) data.name = $scope.name;
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(data));
         };
      }
   };
});
```

```js
app.directive('onDrop', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
         onDrop: '=',
         dropData: '=?'
      },
      link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
         elem[0].ondrop = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
            if ($scope.dropData) data.dropData = $scope.dropData;
            if (data && $scope.onDrop) $scope.onDrop(data);
            $scope.$apply();
            elem[0].classList.remove('dragover');
         };
         elem[0].ondragover = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            elem[0].classList.add('dragover');
         };
         elem[0].ondragleave = function (event) {
            elem[0].classList.remove('dragover');
         };
      }
   };
});
```