# Code to Drag web page/Window by its title bar in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to find library/module which can be used to create draggable web page in angular JS. Currently there are modules in angular which does that for drag and drop boxes within the list. Please do share if anyone had caught into similar problem and has found solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but it kind of reads like you're looking for a library that will help you with drag and drop in Angular.

There was a great post on the this topic before on stackoverflow: [How to Create simple drag and Drop in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555429/how-to-create-simple-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks, I have encountered some of example in the link before but they doesn't fit exactly to my problem. what i want is just simple drag of web page/ windows handle if one have to movie around the page instead of being static just like new window open when you hit the link and move around the screen in angular JS