# Html5 card layout editor

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to html5, I am planning to make a SPA where users can drag drop cards from toolbar into content panel rearrange and save their settings. Not sure where to start is there a prebuilt layout frameworks available that supports this? Any direction would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several modules available to implement jQueryUI Drag and Drop functionality in AngularJS - such as angular-dragdrop. There is also ngDraggable.

Check out this old question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555466/5509627

Comment: Thats a great start, is there a library available to resize them. i.e not have them as perfect squares ?

Comment: Making a element draggable doesn't define it's shape - you can style them as you desire.

Comment: I mean after they dropped it is there a way to give them resize corner that we find in windows bottom right.