# How to create drag and drop to choose image like Stack Overflow using Angular.js?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to create a **"drag and drop"** for choosing image file and preview the selected image similar to "change profile picture" in Gmail.

I want same as this. If I click on image icon in Stack Overflow it will open a modal with "drag and drop" to choose file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create simple drag and Drop in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555429/how-to-create-simple-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs)

Comment: In ask question there will be a image icon. If click on that image icon a drag and drop will open. I want to do same as like that