# Implement html5 drag drop in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Here is the view

```
.container(ng-controller="activityCtrl")
  h3 Edit your plan
  .row
    .one-half.column
      div(draggable="true" ondragstart="onDrag()") I am draggable
```

And i have defined a function inside controller like

```
$scope.onDrag = (evt)=>{
  console.log(evt);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

The error that i am getting is `Reference error onDrag not defined`. I am guessing that it is somewhat because i need to reference the function defined in $scope in `ondragstart`. How can i do the same ?

Comment: If you are manipulating DOM You should use `Directives` in angularJS

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42456136/3543808)

Comment: Anyone got the answer for Angular (v2+) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting the error `Reference error onDrag not defined` because you're referencing a function in HTML5 event which is defined in Angular's scope.

If you really want to access `$scope.onDrag` function in `ondragstart` event, change your html like below:

```
div(draggable="true" ondragstart="angular.element(this).scope().onDrag()") I am draggable
```

> Ideally `angular.element(this).scope()` would be used for debugging purpose 
>   so I would prefer to write a `directive` for drag and drop.

---

Below is the HTML5 drag and drop implementation in AngularJS.
I've replicated the same behavior as shown in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2).

Since you are manipulating `DOM` you should use `directives` in `AngularJS`.

I've implemented two directives

- `drag-me` for `drag`
- `drop-me-on` for `drop`.

You could also use single directive for both, however I prefer separation of concerns.

### HTML:

```
<div id="div1" drop-on-me>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_w3slogo.gif" drag-me  id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" drop-on-me></div>
```

### JS

```
angular
  .module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('dragMe', dragMe)
  .directive('dropOnMe', dropOnMe);

dragMe.$inject = [];

function dragMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.prop('draggable', true);
      element.on('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id)
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
dropOnMe.$inject = [];
function dropOnMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      element.on('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
```

### DEMO

Have a look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/x7euwhhy/)

Comment: I occasionally see a great and well laid out answer like this one :D

Comment: I implemented these two directives and I tried to use it on the cells of a table, but event.srcElement seems to be undefined. event.dataTransfer.setData also does not work. Why is that?

Comment: @Adi Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Adi try to create a plunker/fiddle so that I can look into it!

Comment: I managed to do it, finnaly. There is a known problem with jQuery. I found the workaround here: https://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/angularjs-drag-and-drop/

Answer (score 0):

OnDragStart is not something from the angular context, so you can't use functions defined in $scope or in your controller.

You could use some third party libraries like [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) or [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) or roll your own (see [How to Create simple drag and Drop in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555429/how-to-create-simple-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs) for more details).