# Drag and Drop list, angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, list, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need a drag and drop list with angular, but I need the `$scope.list` change too because I must store the new order in my data base.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354992/drag-and-drop-sortable-ngrepeats-in-angular-js/11923966#11923966) and I used it to get this http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/9sueU/1/

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

The problems is that when I try to change a element from top to down ONE possition is does NOT work.

For example take "one" and take it one position down to get "two,"one","three","four", ... second list should also change but it doesn't.

```
two
one
three
five
four
six
----------
one
two
three
five
four
six
```

both list should be equals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and drop sortable ng:repeats in Angular.JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354992/drag-and-drop-sortable-ngrepeats-in-angular-js)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe I saw that question and tis accepted answer has the same problem, just see it http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/

Comment: it seems to be a bug on ui sortable

Comment: I thought that but I wasn't sure, any suggestion/advice?

Comment: you need to include the sortable.js [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/tree/master/src](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/tree/master/src) and start the module like this var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']); [http://jsfiddle.net/9sueU/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/9sueU/3/)

Comment: yes @AbrahamUribe you are right, thank you very much, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the ui-sortable to work without bugs you need to add the [sortable.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/tree/master/src) and start the module with ui.sortable like this

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);//add .sortable

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sueU/3/

Comment: Is there any option to keep the drag and drop feature but remove the sortable one? I mean, drag and drop will be allowed between different lists only?

Comment: It has a option `sort: false` to get disabled the sorting functionality.